# Place a script immediately after the opening <body> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to place a Google tag manager script and according to Google Tag documentation, the script should be placed immediately after the opening  tag.

Since we cannot change the source code, we have to append the script using the following code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var url = "path/to/js/file";
    var gtm = document.createElement('script');
    gtm.type = 'text/javascript';
    gtm.async = true;
    gtm.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + url;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gtm, s);
})();
</script>
```

It is almost the same as Google analytics script snippet. Now the script is appended right  before the body tag. I am not sure if using jQuery method insertAfter is the proper way to do it or if there is a better way!

I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: i think it's ok. you can use this code.

Comment: Are you sure you want `gtm.src` to be `https:///path/to/js/file` or `http://www./path/to/js/file`?

Comment: Perhaps you should just use `<body><script src="/path/to/js/file"></script>...</body>`.

Comment: @zerkms: The question is: How can I append a script immediately after the opening <body> tag?

Comment: @AaditMShah: Thank you, I have modified the snippet.

Comment: @DawidDziadkiewicz: But the scipt is now appended right before the body tag. I need to append it right after the body tag consider that we have other elements within the body so I cannot use append or appendTo!!

Comment: The position of the `<script>` element in the DOM doesn't matter. Google want the `<script>` element at the top of the body so it is executed before anything else in the body is. Adding it with JS later defeats the object.

Comment: Your Q do not make any sense. GTM docs ask to: `Place the <noscript> code snippet immediately after the <body> tag in your HTML output.` (Not `script`).

Comment: GTM change Setup and install Tag Manager (The Q out of Date):
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696?hl=en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually your code inserts `script` between the `head` and `body` tags. Use this instead:

```
var s = document.body.firstChild;
s.parentNode.insertBefore(gtm, s);
```

Comment: thank you so much. I think this is working but I get an error message in the console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstElementChild' of undefined !!

Comment: Timing? Do you have this IIFE -script in `head` section? If so, wait... how did it work without `lastChild`? In your comment you said it "`is appended right before the body tag`". You've changed something else too...

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`? Just use `.body`.

Comment: Thank you so much Teemu. I chose your answer because it will work with out restrict myself to an element ID after the body tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) for this:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.insertBefore(gtm, body.firstChild);
```

This works even if body tag has no `firstChild`.

Comment: Thank you so much, This returns an error as well when I try it. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined

Comment: Assuming you are using jQuery you can wrap the script loader script inside `$(function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

**This Q is not relevant anymore** (DEC 2021), since GTM change the Setup and install of Tag Manager:

On the "new" setup you should:

> - Place the `<script>` code snippet in the `<head>` of your web page's HTML output, preferably as close to the opening `<head>` tag as
>   possible, but below any dataLayer declarations.
> - **Additionally - Place the `<noscript>` code snippet immediately after the  tag in your HTML output.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696

About `<noscript>` no meaning to add `<noscript>` by any Javascript code (noscript works only in browsers when JavaScript is off).

Answer (score 0):

```
let html = '<p>Your HTML code here</p>';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
```

The insertAdjacentHTML method allows you to insert an HTML string at a specified position relative to an element. In this case, we use 'afterbegin' to insert the HTML just after the opening  tag.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this out - appendChild

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(gtm);
```

Comment: This adds the `script`just before the closing `body` tag : (.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var script = 'The script content here'; // Add your JS as a string,
var url    = 'path/to/js/file';         // Or link to the file.
var scriptNode = document.createElement('script');       // Create a script Element
scriptnode.setAttribute('type', "text/javascript");      // Set the Element's `type` attribute.
// Either:
scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script)); // Add the text to the script Element.
// Or:
scriptNode.setAttribute('src', url);                     // Link to the script
// Place the script Element before the first child of the body.
document.body.insertBefore(scriptNode , document.body.firstChild);
```

So, basically, use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore)

Answer (score -1):

If you are utilizing jQuery, you may be able to use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

```
(function () {
    var url = "path/to/js/file";
    var gtm = document.createElement('script');
    gtm.type = 'text/javascript';
    gtm.async = true;
    gtm.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + url;
    $('body').prepend(gtm);
})();
```

Comment: jQuery uses some quirks when appending `script` tags. It may not inject the script tag itself.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks for the heads up. I just tested it, and it does seem a bit inconsistent.

Answer (score -1):

Can you have an element in your body tag as first element, and append the script just before it. Use  `yourFirstElementIdfromBodyTag.before(here is your appended code goes)` ..

For Example

```
<body>
<your first element> like <input type="hidden" id="hidA" />
//rest code goes here
</body>
```

Now as suggested use `$('#hidA').before('the script code')` . I am sure it will append the script just after `<body>`.